# how do you remove the headers from a kendo grid export to excel using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, excel, asp.net-core-mvc, kendo-grid

I'm using html to create the grid and when I export to excel it's exporting the property names instead of the header names.  I found an example of how to insert custom headers but I can't figure out how to delete the original header. I've looked through the API but can find a method to delete a row from the sheet.

```
var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
sheet.name = "My Sheet";

var myHeaders = [{
    value: "Header 1",
    textAlign: "left",
    background: "#60b5ff",
    color: "#ffffff"
}, {
    value: "Header 2",
    textAlign: "left",
    background: "#60b5ff",
    color: "#ffffff"
}, {
    value: "Header 3",
    textAlign: "left",
    background: "#60b5ff",
    color: "#ffffff"
}];

sheet.rows.splice(0, 0, { cells: myHeaders, type: "header" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter out headers and remove them, and then add your custom headers. Like this:

```
var rows = e.workbook.sheets[0].rows;
var newRows = []
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];

    if (row.type !== "header") 
    {
        newRows.push(row)
    }
}
e.workbook.sheets[0].rows = newRows
```

Below is my complete test code, you can refer to it:

```
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/themes/6.2.0/default/default-main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add the Kendo library by either using the JAVASCRIPT MODULES -->
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/mjs/kendo.all.js" type="module"></script>

<!-- OR by using the BUNDLED JAVASCRIPT -->
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="panel panel-primary">  
    <div class="panel-heading">Test Data from API</div>  
    <div class="panel-body">  
        <div id="Grid"></div> <!--end of grid-->  
    </div> <!--end of panel-body-->  
</div> <!--end of panel-primary-->  

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.4.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
            toolbar: ["excel"],
            excel: {
                fileName: "Demo Excel From Kendo.xlsx",
                filterable: true,  //Allow Filtering
                allPages: true
            },
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "GET", // type: "GET","POST"
                    dataType: "json", //dataType: "json","odata"
                    read: "/api/StudentAPI/GetAllStudents",  //API URL
                },
                pageSize: 5,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            RegNo: {
                                type: "string"
                            },
                            Name: {
                                type: "string"
                            },
                            Address: {
                                type: "string"
                            },
                            PhoneNo: {
                                type: "string"
                            },
                            admissionDate: {
                                type: "date"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            filterable: true, //Allow Filtering
            sortable: true, //Allow Sorting of Columns
            groupable: true, //Allow Grouping
            columnMenu: true, //Show/Hide Columns
            reorderable: true, //Allow Column Reordering
            resizable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true,
                buttonCount: 5
            },
            columns: [{
                field: "regNo",
                title: "Regd No",
                filterable: { multi: true, search: true } //Allow multi select Filter and Search
            }, {
                field: "name",
                title: "Student Name",
                filterable: { multi: true, search: true } //Allow multi select Filter and Search
            }, {
                field: "address",
                title: "Address",
                filterable: { multi: true, search: true } //Allow multi select Filter and Search
            }, {
                field: "phoneNo",
                title: "Phone No",
                filterable: { multi: true, search: true } //Allow multi select Filter and Search
            }, {
                field: "admissionDate",
                title: "Admission Date",
                format: "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", //Date time Formatting Eg: 03-27-2017
                filterable: { multi: true, search: true } //Allow multi select Filter and Search
            }]
        });

        $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").bind("excelExport", function (e) {
            var rows = e.workbook.sheets[0].rows;
            var newRows = []
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var row = rows[i];

                if (row.type !== "header") {
                    newRows.push(row)
                }
            }
            e.workbook.sheets[0].rows = newRows


            var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
            sheet.name = "My Sheet";

            var myHeaders = [{
                value: "Header 1",
                textAlign: "left",
                background: "#60b5ff",
                color: "#ffffff"
            }, {
                value: "Header 2",
                textAlign: "left",
                background: "#60b5ff",
                color: "#ffffff"
            }, {
                value: "Header 3",
                textAlign: "left",
                background: "#60b5ff",
                color: "#ffffff"
            }, {
                value: "Header 4",
                textAlign: "left",
                background: "#60b5ff",
                color: "#ffffff"
            }, {
                value: "Header 5",
                textAlign: "left",
                background: "#60b5ff",
                color: "#ffffff"
            }];

            sheet.rows.splice(0, 0, { cells: myHeaders, type: "header" })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Test Result:
[image]